# Is it possible to use "rows" and "spans" inside modals in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use the modals within Twitter Bootstrap to implement a contact form.

Ideally I would like the first two fieldsets to align next to each other and the third fieldset (containing a textarea and a submit button) to occupy the full width of the modal.

I have tried to use rows and spans to make them play nicely but am not sure on the way to go about this. It seems like there isn't a total of span12 to start with.

Has anyone else achieved anything similar?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, just put it inside the modal body using "row-fluid" class, which will adjust to available space (unless you changed these styles):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">something</div>
<div class="span6">something else</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this coupled with Eric's suggestions worked perfectly. Don't know why I haven't really used row-fluid before. It all gets very confusing with .row, .container, .span's within .span's!

Comment: My experience with <div class="row-fluid"> is that it won't take any span e.g. <input class="span2" type="text">, http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/cm6KQ/1/

Comment: @Labanino: That is pretty unrelated, but take a look at element type (you are using `<input>`, which is styled differently). As a proof that `<div class="row-fluid">` will "take span" is: http://jsfiddle.net/tadeck/cm6KQ/2/ (on `<div>`s, not `<input>`s).

Comment: @Tadeck You need to read carefully. This is part of the original question: Ideally I would like the first two fieldsets to align next to each other and the third fieldset (containing a textarea and a submit button). The guy needs a form in the modal. Now, add an <input class="span2" type="text"> to it and you'll see. I'm talking about the bootstrap span classes (class="span2") not the span tag. This is your html with the <input class="span2"> added to it: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/cm6KQ/3/

Comment: @Labanino: Exactly, careful reading is essential. Couple facts: 1) OP refers to `<fieldset>` (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)), you have given example of `<input>` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)), there is a mismatch, 2) OP accepted my answer, meaning it solved the problem (read this: "_this coupled with Eric's suggestions worked perfectly_"). Really, do not insist on using `<input>` - I see what you are trying to show, but this is kind-of off-topic.

Comment: @Labanino: And here is example with `<fieldset>`: Example with `<fieldset>`: http://jsfiddle.net/tadeck/cm6KQ/4/

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution only using Twitter Bootstrap 3 classes - namely `row`, `col-sm-6` and `clearfix`:

**HTML**

```
...
<div class="modal-body row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <p>First column with fieldset</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
        <p>Second column with fieldset</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <p>Row that expands the whole width of modal &ndash; text area and submit button</p>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Added borders to the columns for viewability below. Note that there is also default Bootstrap padding around the `<p>` tag, not bordered below.

**Rendered preview**

[image: Rendered example of HTML above]

If you want to look at how to structure the title or footer of the modal (before/after the ellipses in the above example), you can look at the [layout of Bootstrap modals here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<div class="modal">
<form class="modal-form">
<div class="modal-header"></div>
<div class="modal-body"> input elements here </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="submit" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal">
```

hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you, though this didn't by itself work for me. Can I ask where "modal-form" comes from?

Comment: Oh sorry, That was just my own custom css. not part of bootstrap