# Bootstrap Modal Dialog. Can the grid system be used within a modal context?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a Bootstrap modal dialog for which I want to layout the various labels and inputs. I have tried using row/column classes but they do not appear to do anything. What are my options here?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I got it working ok...http://www.bootply.com/WAwE3QyUdb

Add a col to the container inside the modal-body.

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Modal header</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        1st col 3
                    </div>

                     <div class="col-md-3">
                         2nd col 3
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-md-3">
                         3rd col 3</div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Cheers Tom.

Comment: I've found the row class works better than the container class - see here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19615212/13153

Comment: Could you please update the bootply link? It's broken. Thanks!

Comment: @TomRudge the structure is container, row, column so the above will fail bootlint E014: https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E014. Additionally, container must be a parent to row so having container as a sibling is also incorrect according to rule E003: https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E003.

Comment: this seems to mess with the margin between the body and the bottom part of the modal. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: @rigdonmr see my answer below; use container-fluid instead of adding on col-md-12

Comment: Please note... the version of bootply has since updated its vanilla bootstrap version. Therefore things has changed with my original bootply. The solution at the time worked for the right purpose. Nearly 2 years on it may be different and should only be used as a reference - therefore please keep this in mind before you comment.

Answer (score 14):

Just add the row class to your modal as per the code below and then you can divide up your modal as you wish:

```
<div class="modal-body row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p>Column One content here ... </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>Column Two content here ... </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.row` must be inside a `.container`/`.container-fluid`

Answer (score 8):

Tom Rudge's answer inspired me.  You don't need to make the container also be a full-width column itself which Matt Dell pointed out will fail linters.

Make the container container-fluid instead!

[bootply showing col-md-12 and container-fluid side by side](http://www.bootply.com/LlMZaJwqam)

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Modal with container fluid</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p>
                            1st col 3
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p>
                            2nd col 3
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p>
                            3rd col 3
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p>
                            4th col 3
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

have a look [bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-grid-system) no need to add `container` or `container-fluid` or `col-*` classes with `modal-body` or inside `modal-body`

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>1st col 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>2nd col 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>3rd col 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>4th col 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[see here](http://www.bootply.com/Nn97PFniCE)

Comment: Perfect, no need a lot of classes!

Comment: It doesn't responsive

Answer (score 3):

From the docs

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-2 .col-md-offset-4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            Level 1: .col-sm-9
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
                Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-grid-system

Comment: It doesn't responsive if the size of modal is small, the responsive depends on parent window.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Bootstrap modal responsive by resetting the container widths:

```
.modal-body {padding: 5px}

.modal-dialog {
@media(min-width: $screen-sm-min){
  width: 600px;
  .container {
    width: 590px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: $screen-md-min){
  width: 800px;
  .container {
    width: 790px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: $screen-lg-min){
  width: 1000px;
  .container {
    width: 990px;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4 you can create a modal container with SCSS.

The `.modal-container` class should be added to the `.modal-dialog`

Variables:

```
$modal-container-max-widths: (
  xs: 90%,
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1200px,
);
```

Coding:

```
@mixin make-modal-max-widths-container-width($max-widths: $modal-container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint, $modal-container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
        max-width: $modal-container-max-width;
    }
  }
}
.modal-container{
   @include make-modal-max-widths-container-width();
}
```

Some additional CSS is recommended.

```
.modal-container{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: ($spacer / 2);
  padding-right: ($spacer / 2);
}
```