# How to divide a web in 2 columns using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to divide a web page made with JSF in two columns, but I'm having problems as it's not displayed as I want. I'll show you what I have.

```
<h:panelGrid id="panelPpal" columns="2" style="width: 100%">
                <h:panelGrid style="width: 100%">
                    <h:form id="projectForm" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h:outputLabel id="lblProjectName" 
                                           value="#{rDisenyo['seccion.crea.nombre']}"
                                           for="projectName"
                                           class="col-md-3 control-label"/>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h:inputText id="projectName" label="Nombre"
                                             value="#{newProjectBacking.nombreProyecto}"
                                             class="form-control"/>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h:outputLabel for="grosorCristal" value="#{rDisenyo['dialog.avanzadas.grosorCristal']}"
                                           class="col-md-3 control-label"/>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h:selectOneMenu id="grosorCristal" 
                                                 class="form-control"
                                                 label="Grosor del Cristal"
                                                 value="#{newProjectBacking.grosorCristal}"
                                                 required="true" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="----------" itemValue="0"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="8 #{rDisenyo['grosor.cristal.milimetro']}" itemValue="8"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="10 #{rDisenyo['grosor.cristal.milimetro']}" itemValue="10"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="12 #{rDisenyo['grosor.cristal.milimetro']}" itemValue="12"/>

                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h:outputLabel for="ralMenu" id="ralLbl"
                                           value="#{rDisenyo['proyecto.opcionesprevias.ral']}"
                                           class="col-md-3 control-label"/>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h:selectOneMenu id="ralMenu" class="form-control" 
                                                 value="#{newProjectBacking.ral}"
                                                 >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="0"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{rDisenyo['proyecto.opcionesprevias.ral.blanco']}" itemValue="1"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{rDisenyo['proyecto.opcionesprevias.ral.crudo']}" itemValue="2"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{rDisenyo['proyecto.opcionesprevias.ral.anodizado']}" itemValue="3"/>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </h:form>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">#{rDisenyo['instrucciones.title']}</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="subtitulo-instruciones">
                                    #{rDisenyo['instrucciones.angulos.grados']}
                                </div>

                                #{rDisenyo['instrucciones.angulos.linea1']}<br/>
                                #{rDisenyo['instrucciones.angulos.linea2']}<br/>
                                <div class="subtitulo-instruciones">
                                    #{rDisenyo['instrucciones.longitud.title']}
                                </div>

                                #{rDisenyo['instrucciones.longitud.linea1']}<br/>
                                <div class="subtitulo-instruciones">
                                    #{rDisenyo['instrucciones.altura.title']}
                                </div>

                                #{rDisenyo['instrucciones.altura.linea1']}<br/>
                                <div class="subtitulo-instruciones">
                                    #{rDisenyo['instrucciones.recogenizq.title']}
                                </div>

                                #{rDisenyo['instrucciones.recogenizq.linea1']}<br/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    Eliga el tipo de proyecto:
                    <h:selectOneRadio id="tipoProyectoRadioButton" value="#{newProjectBacking.tipoProyecto}">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Proyecto A" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Proyecto B" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Proyecto C" />
                        </div>     
                    </h:selectOneRadio>
                    </div>
                </h:panelGrid>


            </h:panelGrid>
```

As you can see, there are two parts in my app: the left one is a form and the right one has instructions and a different form (I know that it isn't yet inside a h:form). I want the right panel to start in the center of the window, but I don't know how to do it. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've found a solution here: [How to divide a Twitter bootstrap modal into 2 parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961932/how-to-divide-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-into-2-parts)

```
<div class="modal-body row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- Your first column here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- Your second column here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap is set up on a grid system, so you can span a total of 12 grids across. The easiest way to think of this, is divide your screen into 3 sections of equal amounts of 4 across. As long as your total columns add up to 12, it will balance out and display properly onto the screen. For centering the column, use the bootstrap class called "text-center". This makes all content within that div center within the column its' self. 
  Example:

```
 <div class = "col-md-6 text-center">
     <!-- Content goes here --> 
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-6 text-center">
      <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
```

The above will divide your content into two equal columns and center all the content enclosed within the div.

For a more visual representation of the grid system (i recommend checking this out), look here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html