# Modal behaving abnormally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to build a two column layout in a bootstrap modal. This is the code:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="product-showcase-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="product-showcase" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <div class="container col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <img src="http://localhost/haya/img/hijabs/dark%20grey.jpg" id="product_image" width="200px" height="auto" style="display: inline;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                             <h3 id="product_name">Dark Gray</h3>

                            <p id="new_price">$3.00</p>
                            <p style="text-decoration: line-through;" id="old_price">$4.35</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning">Add to cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

I have no idea why is this happening. Can anyone resolve this?

**UPDATE 1:**
I removed the `col-xs-12` class from the `container` div. Now the container is in the modal's body but it's has taken a width of 100% (my screen's width). Result:
[image]

Comment: That looks like a float issue without a clearfix.  Try this SO question & answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848258/is-it-possible-to-use-rows-and-spans-inside-modals-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions no, I tried to remove the `col-xs-12` class from the `container` div. But then the container took on a width of 100%(my screen's width). I don't know how to resolve that now! :/

Comment: Did you add the clearfix from the other solution?  Try putting it with your modal-body class.

Comment: No. Where do I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add a clearfix to the modal-body.  This will fix the float item issue where the container doesn't fully expand.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6310/

```
<div class="modal-body clearfix">
```